# Listing files in linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I am using fedora 17 in which i am using the command "ls" to list the files under the current directory as follows.

```
          [user@test test]# ls
```

Is there any way to list files in another directory without changing the current directory

I want something like this

```
         [user@test test]# /usr/lib/ then list the files.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend `ls --help` as a starting point:

```
$ ls --help
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
[...]
```

For more information have a look into the man pages, which are available for most of the linux commands. (`man ls`).

The answer to your specific question is astonishing simple, just use

```
ls /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

`ls /usr/lib` ?

Is there a reason why that doesn't work, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use

> ls /usr/lib

as suggested above you can start by using **man** as **man ls** it will give you explanation
of many linux commands